# Motion Sensing by Camera in iOS

Tags: ios, opencv, camera

I am working on an app in iOS that will occur an event if camera detects some changes in image or we can say motion in image. Here   I am not asking about face recognition or a particular colored image motion, And I got all result for OpenCV when I searched, And I also found that we can achieve this by using gyroscope and accelerometer both , but how??

I am beginner in iOS.So my question is , Is there any framework or any easy way to detect motion or motion sensing by camera.And How to achieve?

For Example if I move my hand before camera then it will show some message or alert.

And plz give me some useful and easy to understand links about this.
Thanx

Comment: this isn't an official answer, [but there are lots of rumors](http://www.google.com/search?q=motion+detection+ios) that iOS 7 is going to include some kind of Motion Detecting features.

Comment: So is there no way to achieve this MichaelDautermann.

Comment: I didn't say that @Shyam; what I did say is that Motion Detection might become a lot more easier in just a matter of a couple weeks.  You can also do a search to see if some SDK or open source solution already exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you want is some kind of crude motion detection, my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework has a GPUImageMotionDetector within it.

This admittedly simple motion detector does frame-to-frame comparisons, based on a low-pass filter, and can identify the number of pixels that have changed between frames and the centroid of the changed area. It operates on live video and I know some people who've used it for motion activation of functions in their iOS applications.

Because it relies on pixel differences and not optical flow or feature matching, it can be prone to false positives and can't track discrete objects as they move in a frame. However, if all you need is basic motion sensing, this is pretty easy to drop into your application. Look at the FilterShowcase example to see how it works in practice.

Comment: When I tried to run FilterShowCase example then it is showing errors in GPUImageBilateralFilter.m file : - Use of undeclared identifier '_distanceNormalizationFactor' Here I am using Xcode 4.3.3  and I tried it in Xcode 4.1 then it is showing errors like :- Unknown type name '__unsafe_unretained' @Brad Larson

Comment: What is the meaning of weak-link Core Video framework ??? You wrote in the introduction part of framework. @Brad Larson

Comment: @ShyamDixit - Xcode 4.1 is fairly ancient at this point, don't use that for anything. You need to have ARC support for this framework to work, and I recommend Xcode 4.4 or higher. Also, use the latest code from the repository, because the `distanceNormalizationFactor` property is correctly defined there for older Xcode versions, but that was fixed a few months ago. In the latest Xcode, to weak-link something, change the framework's status from Required to Optional in the Link Binary With Libraries build phase.

Comment: how to do motion sensor like just dance application has done...like image comes and user have to perform like that..

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly understand what you mean here:

> Here I am not asking about face recognition or a particular colored
>   image motion, because I got all result for OpenCV when I searched

But I would suggest to go for opencv as you can use opencv in IOS. Here is a good link which helps you to [setup opencv in ios](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/).

There are lot of opencv motion detection codes online and here is [one among them](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/simple-webcam-intruder-alarm-part-1/#more-381), which you can make use of.

You need to convert the `UIImage` ( image type in IOS ) to `cv::Mat` or `IplImage` and pass it to the opencv algorithms. You can convert using [this link](https://sites.google.com/site/iprinceps/Home/iphone-1/converting-images-between-uiimage-and-iplimage) or [this](https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone/blob/master/OpenCVClient/UIImage+OpenCV.mm).