# Motion detection from camera live stream in iOS

Tags: ios, core-image, motion-detection

I am making an application in which i have to open the camera and track the motion from camera live video/stream. and then detect the number of faces in the current frame.

I have done the face detection part by using CIDetector but unable to do the Motion detection.
Can any one please guide me how to do it.

I have used the GPUImage but it does not support multiple face detection.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Motion Sensing by Camera in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570807/motion-sensing-by-camera-in-ios)

Comment: Yes but GPUImage does not have multiple face detection

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a similar app. I used OpenCV to do both motion detection and face detection. The process would involve converting your Pixel Buffer ref into an OpenCV Mat object, converting this to grayscale and performing absDiff() and threshold() functions to calculate the diff (motion) between two images.

You can then process the same frame again for faces. This maybe not as efficient as GPUImage which can now do motion detection as well using GPU acceleration.

```
    int motionValue;

    // Blur images to reduce noise and equalize
    cv::Mat processedFrame = cv::Mat(originFrame.size(), CV_8UC1);
    cv::blur(originFrame, processedFrame, cv::Size(2,2));

    // Get absolute difference image
    cv::Mat diffMat;
    cv::absdiff(processedFrame, prevFrame, diffMat);

    // Apply threshold to each channel and combine the results
    cv::Mat treshMat;
    cv::threshold(diffMat, treshMat, kCCAlgorithmMotionSensitivity, 255, CV_THRESH_TOZERO);

    // Find all contours
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::findContours(treshMat, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    // Count all motion areas
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > intruders;
    for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++) {
        double area = cv::contourArea(contours[i]);
        //NSLog(@"Area %d = %f",i, area);
        if (area > kCCAlgorithmMotionMinAreaDetection){
            intruders.push_back(contours[i]);
            motionValue += area;
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes Vald i have make my whole application using GPU image . but unfortunately it does not have the face recognition feature in it. Thats why i am using the Open cv. can you please give me the code of motion detection in open cv.because i have tried this logic what you have told but there are many issues

Comment: Check my edited response. This is just a snippet. You would have to keep reference of the previous frame every time you call the compare function. This would be snippet of compare function to show you the diff way of detecting motion and calculating a motion value.